# Does this symbol in the pictures below represent height above ground level or altitude above sea level?

Tags: altitude, jeppesen, symbology

Does this symbol in the pictures below represent height above ground level or altitude above sea level? There are huge differences between them and the Grid MORA values, so I think there may be heights from the ground, but I couldn't find the answer from the sources.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Jeppesen Charts legend](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Introduction-to-Jeppesen-Navigation-Charts.pdf) explains the symbol as follows:

> [image: Approach Planview]
>
> 17 — Some, but not all, terrain high points and man-made structures are depicted **along with their elevations**.
> Generally only high points 400’ or more above the airport elevation are shown.
>
> 18 — Arrow indicates the highest of the portrayed high points within the planview area only.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So these numbers correspond to the **elevation** above mean sea level (AMSL) of the terrain high point or man-made structure in feet.